# PHP files on Amazon S3 Not Working

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Total newb question I'm sure but I'm new to S3 and trying to open a simple PHP file on my server. Yet it prompts to Save the file each time instead of opening it. Is S3 not able to run PHP files?

Comment: No, I isn't able to run php files..... S3 is a file storage system, not a system for executing code

Comment: You need to have a web-server. Such example would be an Apache web-server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Amazon S3 is a `storage` not a `server`.

> Amazon S3: 
>   Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), provides developers and IT teams with secure, durable, highly-scalable object storage. Amazon S3 is easy to use, with a simple web service interface to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere on the web. With Amazon S3, you pay only for the storage you actually use. There is no minimum fee and no setup cost.

Link: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

> Amazon EC2:
>   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) is a web service that provides resizable compute capacity in the cloud. It is designed to make web-scale cloud computing easier for developers.

Link: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

You want to get an instance from `EC2` and install `php` on its linux server.

AWS has a great tutorial to do so [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

Basically AWS EC2 linux servers are the same as any other linux server except lots of features from AWS so you can follow other tutorials on how to install PHP on an Apache2 servers.

Good luck!

EDIT: However, you can host a `static` website. Static website is a website that shows the same content for all users. Basic informational websites are the example. As opposed to `static` website, `dynamic` website is a website that shows different contents for different users. The purpose of `php script` is to create a dynamic website, so you must look for other options than AWS S3. So EC2 would be great fit for you.